# Ant: failes to compile despite classpath specified and file being seemingly valid

Tags: java, ant, sling

My file (this is just a minimal example to test this import, because it went wrong elsewhere): TestTim_src/TestTim.java

```
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap;

class TestTim {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printLn("aaaaap");
}

}
```

TestTim.xml:

```
<project>
<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${basedir}/TestTim_src">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/unzipped_dependencies/">
                <include name="org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.class" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
</project>
```

i run it like this:

ant -f TestTim.xml -v compile

i get this error:

```
[javac] File to be compiled:
[javac]     C:\XXX\TestTim_src\TestTim.java
[javac] C:\XXX\TestTim_src\TestTim.java:1: error: package org.apache.sling.api.resource does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap;
[javac]                                     ^
```

I checked that this file is not empty and contains something seemingly legible. Sling is open source, so i could just use the source but to avoid dependency problems i'm trying to use the compiled file.

```
# javap -c unzipped_dependencies/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.class

Compiled from "ValueMap.java"
public interface org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap extends java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> {
public static final org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap EMPTY;

public abstract <T> T get(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<T>);

public abstract <T> T get(java.lang.String, T);

static {};
  Code:
     0: new           #1                  // class org/apache/sling/api/wrappers/ValueMapDecorator
     3: dup
     4: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/util/Collections.emptyMap:()Ljava/util/Map;
     7: invokespecial #3                  // Method org/apache/sling/api/wrappers/ValueMapDecorator."<init>":(Ljava/util/Map;)V
    10: putstatic     #4                  // Field EMPTY:Lorg/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap;
    13: return
}
```

I do not know why javac is not picking up this import. I'm using cygwin and oracle java on top of windows 10.

Comment: You can try 'echo'-ing classpath from ant to see what all is available during compilation in classpath. Also please use an ide like eclipse or intellij. This is just unnecessary and pointless suffering.

Comment: thanks for the tip. indeed im not a big eclipse/intellij user. but im not sure how that would help with a precompiled jar.

Comment: IDEs are very good at pointing out issues like these. This seems to be just a classpath issue. Also it looks like the issue would go away if you remove the <include> element from ant config. Since the class structure starts from classpath, your current config would work if the .class file contained the folder structure org/apache/sling.... ( as in a jarfile)